# How to select elements like question1, question2, question3,... in JQuery form validation plug-in?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, validation

I am using jQuery and the jQuery Validation plugin to validate inputs. Below is the code. Now there are many inputs named like question1, question2, question3, question4,... How can I place validation on them? I mean how to select them all together?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#item").validate({
        rules: {
            title: {
                required: true,
                minlength:40
            },
            content: {
                required: true,
                minlength:100,
                maxlength:2000
            }
        },
        messages: {
        }
    });
});
```

The code:

```
 $("input[name^='question']"): {
            required: true,
             minlength:40

        }
```

does not work.

Comment: I am using JQuery validation plug-in

Comment: What do you mean by "select them all together"? More clarification is required as everyone seems to have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 2):

Several ways. You can use the comma separator:

```
$("#question1, #question2, #question3")...
```

You can use [`add()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/add):

```
$("#question1").add("#question2").add("#question3")..
```

If question1 is a name and not an ID, use an attribute selector:

```
$(":input[name^=question]")...
```

But I would recommend using a class:

```
<input type="text" name="question1" class="question">
<input type="text" name="question2" class="question">
<input type="text" name="question3" class="question">
```

with:

```
$(":input.question")...
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but not what I want. My question is misunderstood by you.

Comment: Some clarification of your question is required in that case.

Comment: I want the selector to be used within  $("#item").validate().
input[name^='question']: { required: true, minlength:40 } does not work.

Comment: just inputs whose names begin with "question".

Comment: I am using Jquery form validation plugin, the syntax of select is used within the function of validate(), as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean `<input type="text" name="question1" />`, then try the following jquery selector:

```
$("input[name^='question']");
```

It will return a list of all of those elements.

This is how to do it (assuming the code you posted works for one element):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name^='question']").validate({
        rules: {
            title: {
                required: true,
                minlength:40
            },
            content: {
                required: true,
                minlength:100,
                maxlength:2000
            }
        },
        messages: {
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It is Jquery form validation plugin, not simply Jquery.

Comment: input[name^='question']: {
         required: true,
          minlength:40
         
        }  does not work.

Comment: No,$("input[name^='question']") are just input elements within the form item, title and content are their peers.

Comment: "item" is the name of a form. Questions elements are inputs within the form of "item".