# How to select elements like question1, question2, question3,… in JQuery form validation plug-in?

Tags: jquery, plugins, validation

Exact duplicate of [How to select elements like question1, question2, question3,… in JQuery form validation plug-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739991/how-to-select-elements-like-question1-question2-question3-in-jquery-form-va)

```
<input type="text" name="question1" />
<input type="text" name="question2" />
<input type="text" name="question3" />
<input type="text" name="question4" />

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#item").validate({
        rules: {
            title: {
                required: true,
                minlength:40
            },
         ???: {
                required: true,
                minlength:40
            },
            content: {
                required: true,
                minlength:100,
                maxlength:2000
            }
        },
        messages: {
        }
    });
});

$(":input[name^=question]") and `$(":input.question")` are used in Jquery general, not in Jquery form validation plug-in.
```

Comment: Don't duplicate questions. You posted the same question only 20min ago

Comment: But I have not got the question and it seems that nobody will answer my previous question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules:{
        "question1":{requred:true}
    }
    messages: {
        "question1":{requred:true}
    }
})
```

Comment: well that's a problem. if only rules and messages are objects then you could just add to rules or message in the same exact fashion.